# UIView follows path while dragging

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, calayer, cgpoint

[image]

I want UIView to follows path AB while user dragging it. For each CD I need to calculate y.

How to calculate P(x,y) and h?

Comment: Is your question about a math or ios development? If you need help with development please post code where you are trying to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

h = AC * BD / CB

P.S. Are you sure UIView's method

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations
```

is not suitable for you?

Comment: No, because I want to drag view, not just animate it.

Comment: As you wish :) was `h = AC * BD / CB` helpful? If yes, please accept the answer.